# Rollback transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, ef-code-first

I had next code:

```
C#

Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("sp_myProc")

SQL



 procedure sp_myProc
    begin try
       begin tran
              insert....
              delete....
       commit tran
    end try
    begin catch
         goto error;
    end catch

    error:
        if @@trancount > 0
           rollback tran
```

This code didn't work properly as I got due to  `ExecuteSqlCommand` also open abmient transaction and `@@trancount` in case of error, rollback all transactions including from `ExecuteSqlCommand`. And EF generates error:

> "Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates that a COMMIT or ROLLBACK
>   TRANSACTION statement is missing"

my question #1: Am'I right about understanding of current error?

`my` question #2: if I change stored procedure sp_myProc to view like:

```
   set xact abort on;
   begin tran
          insert....
          delete....
   commit tran
```

what caveats or errors can I have?

Comment: In addition to SET XACT_ABORT ON, move the conditional rollback to the catch block.

Comment: it doesn't work - raise error "Message = "Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates that a COMMIT or ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement is missing. Previous count = 1, current count = 0."

Comment: It looks like  ExecuteSqlCommand starts a transaction for you.  Transaction handling should be done by the client or in the proc, but not both.  Otherwise, a rollback in the proc will also rollback the client transaction.

Comment: Yes, ExecuteSqlCommand inside starts a transaction. My question was: if I apply second version of my code will I have any caveats?

Comment: The caviat with any transaction handling in the proc invoked with ExecuteSqlCommand is you will get the tran count error following a rollback.  So why have any in the proc at all?

Comment: I'm afraid the procedure can be called by smbd from SSMS.

Comment: If you must use the same proc from EF and SSMS, I think your only recourse is to gracefully handle this specific SqlException in the C# code.  That should only occur in a rollback scenario.